# How to fill the screen with a div, then center it once the screen gets too big (max-height reached)?

Tags: vertical-alignment, css

Goal:

- When the width and height of the window are both small, the div should be the same size as the window;
- When the width of the window is too big (>max-width), the div should keep its width as max-width, and be horizontally centered.
- When the height of the window is too big (>max-height), the div should keep its height as max-height, **and be vertically centered**.

The example below has achieved everything, except for the last point.

How to center this div vertically in the window? I.e., I want the red areas to behave like the green ones, but just vertically instead of horizontally.

(This design is intended for a responsive design for mobile devices' screens. No JS involvement if possible.)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
        <head>
                <style>
                        body,html{
                                height:100%;
                                margin:0px;
                                background:green;
                                }
                        #t1{
                                position:relative;
                                height:100%;
                                max-width:640px;
                                margin:0 auto;
                                background-color:red;
                        }
                        #t1-1{
                                position:absolute;
                                height:100%;
                                max-height:640px;
                                width:100%;
                                background-color:#dddddd;

                                overflow:hidden;/*demo purpose*/
                        }
                        /*the following stuff are for demo only*/
                        img{
                                position:absolute;
                                opacity:0.5;
                        }
                        img.w{
                                width:100%;
                        }
                        img.h{
                                height:100%;
                        }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="t1">
                        <div id="t1-1">
                                <img class="h" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
                                <img class="w" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
                        </div>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

P.S. In this example, some desktop browsers internally set a min-width value to the whole thing (e.g. 400px in Chrome), unabling the div to keep shrinking horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

You may need a little javascript to make it work:

First of all, you need an `<div>` element to layout, so I called it **mask**:

```
<div id="mask"></div>
```

Then, style it to fill the entire document, and give a `max-width` and `max-height`:

```
<style>
    #mask {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 400px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

This style do not perform the **centering** work, so you need your javascript to do it, we have a `layoutMask` function to determine if the div should be centered or not:

```
var mask = document.getElementById('mask');
function layoutMask() {
    // here 400 is the same as the max-width style property
    if (window.innerWidth >= 400) {
        mask.style.left = '50%';
        // to ensure centering, this sould be (max-width / 2)
        mask.style.marginLeft = '-200px';
    }
    else {
        mask.style.left = '';
        mask.style.marginLeft = '';
    }

    // the same as width
    if (window.innerHeight >= 400) {
        mask.style.top = '50%';
        mask.style.marginTop = '-200px';
    }
    else {
        mask.style.top = '';
        mask.style.marginTop = '';
    }
}
```

At last, assign this function to the `resize` event, and execute immediately to ensure the `<div>` got layed correctly on first load:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', layoutMask);
}
else {
    window.attachEvent('onresize', layoutMask);
}
layoutMask();
```

I tried this on my chrome, but I'm sure it does not work under IE6 since IE6 doesn't support the `position: fixed;` style, but it should work in most browsers.

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/otakustay/bPjHf/) for test.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, with `height:100%` it is not possible. You need to use `<center>` to keep it in center horizontally and vertically. You may need to use margins also. Like:

```
margin-top:18%;
margin-left:40%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `@media` query to achieve this effect

```
@media (min-height: 640px) {
    #t1-1 {
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -320px;
    }
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tS7v/) for testing.